# Angular application notify surrounding JQuery app of an event

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular 1.5 app on a page surrounded by a jQuery application. I want to notify the surrounding page or jQuery application that an event has occurred in the AngularJS app i.e validation issue. How can i do this?

Comment: add an event listner

Comment: Thanks Mohsin, but how do I throw the event from the Angular app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Add an event listener

```
document.addEventListener("name-of-event", function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail); // Prints "Example of an event"
});
```

// Create the event

```
var event = new CustomEvent("name-of-event", { "detail": "Example of an event" });
```

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event

```
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```